# Unset ID column in entity PUT rest controller method

Tags: java, spring

Say I have a PUT method in a rest controller.

I can hand it a Hibernate entity object EntityClass to update EntityClass of id entityId through the request.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{entityId}", method = RequestMethod.PUT, consumes = JSON, produces = JSON)
public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> saveEntity(
        @PathVariable Long entityID,
        @RequestBody EntityClass request
) throws Exception {

}

@Entity
public class EntityClass{
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, insertable = true, updatable = false)
    private Integer id;
}
```

So, the Url would be the place that the id is specified, rather than the entity.
Is there a default way to throw an exception when an entity is handed with the id column set?
Or rather, what is the correct way to go about this?